# Queue task completion response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, queue, coravel

I have a queue. I use it for some task.
After I invoke the queue in a controller, I want to wait for that task to finish.
When that task is finished then only I return the response from the controller,

Will doing this defeat the concept of using queue.

I want to use the queue invocable somewhat like this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> controller(int x)
{
       int x = 0;
       x = _queue.QueueInvocableWithPayload<QueueInvokeClass,PayloadModel>(
              new PayloadModel(x));
       while(x != 1){}
       return Ok();
}


public int Invoke()
{
      //---Task---
      return 1;
}
```

I wanted to try something like this, only issue is I won't get the return 1 value from Invoke method.

Perhaps I can try making a flag in the database, and use that to check if the task has been finished.

My question is , should I be using a queue in such way, if yes then can it be achieved using the concept in the code above.

Comment: No, you should use a queue like this and, no, it can't work with the concept code you've presented.

Comment: not even with the flag concept?

Comment: No. Especially not. What you should do is `await` a task as you're in a `async Task<IActionResult>` method anyway. That's the whole point of `async`/`await` for methods like this.